# pow из math.h работает не так, как ожидается

Tags: c, математика, gcc, codeblocks

Есть некий код(решение задачи https://otvet.mail.ru/question/216978143 ):
https://ideone.com/htRIC7
В строке 20 используется самописный метод Pow.

```
b+=a%10*Pow(10,i);
```

Проблема в том, что при замене его на (int)(pow()) из math.h

```
b+=a%10*((int)(pow(10,i)));
```

и компиляции через GNU GCC в CodeBlocks программа перестает работать (не выводит числа), однако на ideone отрабатывает корректно:
https://ideone.com/jjJ1rT

Есть ли отличия между двумя записями, если i - int. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: `(int)`?  `pow` работает с типом `double`.

Comment: А что, нельзя преобразовать дабл в инт?

Comment: Скажем так, при смешении типов, рано или поздно что-то взрывается. Почитайте [там](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18155883/1892060).

Comment: Попробуйте так: b+=a%10*((int)(pow((double)10,(double)i)));

Answer (score 1):

Простите великодушно, но ваше решение из серии - зачем просто, если можно сложно?

Даже простой перебор написать гораздо проще:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int Reverse(int a)
{
    int b = 0;
    while(a)
    {
        b = b*10+a%10;
        a/=10;
    }
    return b;
}

int main(){
    int value=7064496;
    for(int i = sqrt(value)+1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if(Reverse(i)*i==value){printf("%i %i", i, Reverse(i)); return 0;}
    }
}
```